# How to use jQuery with different id of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have something like this in index.html where each box has 2 images and I'm trying to fade between images for each box ( which has different id /item.id/ ).
Please note that I use ng-repeat and that's why  I use the angular id

```
<div class= "fading" id= "{{item.id}}">
  <div class="image-transition" >
    <div id= "img1" style="background:url('{{item.images[item.image]}}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
    <div id= "img2" style="background:url('{{item.images[item.image]}}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I have this in the index.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#img1").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#img2").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

the thing is that the above jQuery only works for the first box and I want to make it work for every item.id in AngularJS. How to do that ?

Please if something is not clear, comment it out before you down vote my question. I'm new and I would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks for your time

Comment: So you want to find every div with the class `.fading` and fade out the first image and fade in the second?

Comment: @Archer yes so each box ( which has different angular id ) has an array of image and I want to fade out from one and fade in into another. This is not much a problem. I tried this `$scope.item.id.$(document).ready(function() .....` but it didn't work.

Comment: do you use same ids among your divs? If so the you have to change this each id is unique ... `img1` has to used once in your document etc ..

Comment: @AmaniBenAzzouz the first given code is inside a ng-repeat so that's why I use angular ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to fix your HTML : you cannot use same ids inside a loop , in your case `repeat` loop, IDs are unique each ID have to used once in your document.

Supposing that your `item.id` is unique you can do this:

```
<div class= "fading" id= "{{item.id}}">
  <div class="image-transition" >
    <div id= "img1_{{item.id}}" style="background:url('{{item.images[item.image]}}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
    <div id= "img2_{{item.id}}" style="background:url('{{item.images[item.image]}}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use Jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //select image under image-transition div and id starting by img1_
    $('.image-transition').find($('[id^=img1_]')).fadeOut("slow");
    $('.image-transition').find($('[id^=img2_]')).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's a generic thing that happens to all matching divs then you can do this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // find all elements with the class name "fading"
    $(".fading").each(function() {

        // for each of these elements, find all the divs inside
        var $div = $(this).find("div");

        // fade out the first and fade in the second
        $div.eq(0).fadeOut("slow");
        $div.eq(1).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

You can just get rid of the ID attributes on the divs inside `.fading`, since they'll be repeated in your example so they're of no use anyway.  You could add a class name instead, so you can use that in the selector above, to make it more specific.

You could alternatively do it all with pure css...

```css
.fading div { float: left; height: 100px; width: 100px; }
.fade-out { animation-name: fade-out; background-color: red; opacity: 1; }
.fade-in { animation-name: fade-in; background-color: blue; opacity: 0; }
.fade-in, .fade-out { animation-duration: 5s; animation-fill-mode: forwards; }
@keyframes fade-out { 0% { opacity: 1; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
```

```html
<div class="fading">
  <div class="fade-out"></div>
  <div class="fade-in"></div>
</div>
<div class="fading">
  <div class="fade-out"></div>
  <div class="fade-in"></div>
</div>
<div class="fading">
  <div class="fade-out"></div>
  <div class="fade-in"></div>
</div>
```